# Can I have horizontal scrolling in the installed application on the Sense 5.5?

Tags: applications, htc-sense, htc, htc-one, menu

I have an HTC One with Sense 5.5 installed. In Sense 5.5 the installed application menu have a vertical scrolling. I'd prefer to have horizontal scrolling.

Can I change this setting in some way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a third-party launcher app like [Nova Launcher](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.launcher&hl=en). Nova will let you scroll vertically or horizontally via `Nova Settings > Drawer > Drawer Style`.

[image]

Comment: I love Nova launcher, but if you want the Sense widgets you cannot have them in Nova. Sense is VERY restrictive and from what I can see on my HTC One there is no option other than the default... This is the usual with Sense. The alternative is to root and install some modded Sense roms or such.. but that's a messy road if you're not sure what you're doing!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible.

I had a look around in the settings, but also couldn't find something to change this scrolling. But there is not a single Sense version that I can remember where it was possible to change this setting. So seems very unlikely that they will have changed this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same reaction about missing the horizontal scrolling. I couldn't figure out Nova Launcher the first time around, so I uninstalled it (but might try it again later - looks cool).

However, I also found this in a [review](http://www.laptopmag.com/reviews/smartphones/htc-one-t-mobile.aspx), which may help you:

> The app menu in HTC Sense 5.0 has a clean and streamlined feel to it,
>   and scrolls up and down rather than left to right like the S4.
>   However, if you happen to scroll horizontally out of habit, the app
>   drawer will automatically move to the next screen.

I tried it, and it worked for me. Not as smooth as being able to page horizontally by default, but for me it's good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to Keep all the needed icons on home pages, so that you can horizontally swipe to launch the application you need and no need of opening Applications menu every time.